# for-loop Uglify in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, uglifyjs

i'm using Uglify-js to min javascript files. here is the code

```
@echo on
for /r %%F in (*.js) do uglifyjs %%~dpnF%%~xF -o %%~dpnF.min%%~xF

rem pause 1
pause 
md min-js

rem pause 2
pause
```

it creates all min.js files but it doesn't go to next line "pause" neither it creates new folder "md min-js". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a `call` in front of uglifyjs. I assume that it's a batch file, too

Comment: it did work! but now it gives me an error: "can't read file c:\My". The full path is c:\My Test\minify. any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: @CarlitosOverflow:  You need to put your paths and filenames in quotation marks.

Comment: @indiv: adding quotation marks such "%%~dpnF%%~xF" did work, thanks

Comment: Since you found the solution, please post it as an answer and accept it; so the question does not remain open in the OS database...